# How to plot pcolor colorbar in a different subplot - matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subplot, colorbar

I am trying to split my plots in different subplots.. What I want to achieve is to put a colorbar for a subplot in a different subplot.
Right now I am using:

```
# first graph
axes = plt.subplot2grid((4, 2), (0, 0), rowspan=3)
pc = plt.pcolor(df1, cmap='jet')

# second graph
axes = plt.subplot2grid((4, 2), (3, 0))
plt.pcolor(df2, cmap='Greys')

# colorbar
plt.subplot2grid((4, 2), (0, 1), rowspan=3)
plt.colorbar(pc)
```

But the result is the following (notice the unwanted empty graph left to the colorbar):
[image: Wrong graph]

What can I do to print only the colorbar without the left plot?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`colorbar()` accepts a `cax` keyword argument that allows you to specify the `axes` object that the colorbar will be drawn on.

In your case, you would change your colorbar call to the following:

```
# colorbar
axes = plt.subplot2grid((4, 2), (0, 1), rowspan=3)
plt.colorbar(pc, cax=axes)
```

This will take up the whole space given by `subplot2grid`; you can adjust this to be more reasonable either by having the main axes take up many more columns than the colorbar axes, or by setting up the `gridspec` explicitly. For example, your figure may be easier to tweak with the following:

```
from matplotlib import gridspec
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2, height_ratios=(3, 1), width_ratios=(9, 1))

# first graph
axes = plt.subplot(gs[0,0])
pc = plt.pcolor(df1, cmap='jet')

# second graph
axes = plt.subplot(gs[1,0])
plt.pcolor(df2, cmap='Greys')

# colorbar
axes = plt.subplot(gs[0,1])
plt.colorbar(pc, cax=axes)
```

Then you can just change `height_ratios` and `width_ratios` to your liking.

Comment: It works but the colorbar is enlarged horizontally. How to mantain the same default ratio? I tried passing `aspect` keyword but it is not accepted, so I falled back to doing it explicitly incrementing the number of columns for the graphics..

Comment: I added a section to the answer with another way to have the colorbar axes take up less space.

Comment: No problem :) Happy plotting!

Comment: Just one thing: the second subplot call lacks gs variable

Comment: Can you change the `plt` calls to be OO calls as you are already creating and keeping track of the axes objects?  I know I can edit it my self, but that seems rude.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use **ax** instead of **cax**.

```
# colorbar
axes = plt.subplot2grid((4, 2), (0, 1), rowspan=3)
plt.colorbar(pc, ax=axes)
```

Comment: No, `cax` sets the axes that the color bar is drawn to, `ax` is only used to determine which axes to steal space from if `cax` is not passed in.