# How to plot contourf colorbar in different subplot - matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is a very similar question to ["How to plot pcolor colorbar in a different subplot - matplotlib"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18874135/how-to-plot-pcolor-colorbar-in-a-different-subplot-matplotlib). I am trying to plot a filled contour plot and a line plot with a shared axis and the colorbar in a separate subplot (i.e. so it doesn't take up space for the contourf axis and thus muck up the x-axis sharing). However, the x-axis in my code does not rescale nicely:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

z = np.random.rand(20, 20)
x, y = np.arange(20), np.arange(20)
y2 = np.random.rand(20)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
gs = mpl.gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2, height_ratios=[1, 2], width_ratios=[2, 1])
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0], sharex=ax1)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 1])
cont = ax1.contourf(x, y, z, 20)
plt.tick_params(which='both', top=False, right=False)
ax2.plot(x, y2, color='g')
plt.tick_params(which='both', top=False, right=False)
cbar = plt.colorbar(cont, cax=ax3)
cbar.set_label('Intensity', rotation=270, labelpad=20)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

which produces an x-axis scaled from 0 to 20 (inclusive) rather than 0 to 19, which means there is unsightly whitespace in the filled contour plot. Commenting out the `sharex=ax1` in the above code means that the x-axis for the contour plot is scaled nicely, but not for the line plot above it and the `plt.tick_params` code has no effect on either axis.

[image: plot]

Is there a way of solving this?

Comment: I included the plot as image. It is rather difficult to understand the problem by your description alone. Feel free to edit and (re)move it, if you do not like the place.

Comment: `ax1.set_xlim(0, 19)` should be a quick workaround.

Comment: Thanks, cel. Strangely, adding the `ax1.set_xlim` doesn't work. I should have mentioned this in the question. It seems to be unexpected (to me) behaviour of `contourf` which is interfering with or blocking the axis methods.

Comment: setting the `xlim` as suggested by @cel works for me: http://i.imgur.com/LvR3UnF.png

Comment: Sorry, @cel and @tom, I was being an idiot. Using `set_xlim` works fine. Also, using `ax1.set_params()` works, whereas the `plt.set_params()` doesn't. No idea why.

Answer (score 2):

You could also turn off the autoscaling of x-axis for all subsequent call of plot on this axis so that it keeps the range set by `contourf` and `sharex=True` :

```
ax2.set_autoscalex_on(False)
```

This comes even before your call to `ax2.plot()` and I think it is better than calling `ax2.set_xlim(0, 19)` since you do not need to know what are the actual limit of your x-axis that may be needed.

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes
 
z = np.random.rand(20, 20)
x, y = np.arange(20), np.arange(20)
y2 = np.random.rand(20)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
gs = mpl.gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1, height_ratios=[1, 2], width_ratios=[2])
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0], sharex=ax1)
cont = ax1.contourf(x, y, z, 20)
plt.tick_params(which='both', top=False, right=False)

ax2.set_autoscalex_on(False)
ax2.plot(x, y2, color='g')

axins = inset_axes(ax1,
           width="5%", # width = 10% of parent_bbox width
           height="100%", # height : 50%
           loc=6,
           bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 0., 1, 1),
           bbox_transform=ax1.transAxes,
           borderpad=0,
       )

cbar = plt.colorbar(cont, cax=axins)
plt.show()
```

[image: example]

Comment: `width_ratios=[2,1])` should be `width_ratios=[2])`

Answer (score -1):

You can use inset_axes for this without added another axis.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes

z = np.random.rand(20, 20)
x, y = np.arange(20), np.arange(20)
y2 = np.random.rand(20)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
gs = mpl.gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2, height_ratios=[1, 2], width_ratios=[2, 1])
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0], sharex=ax1)
cont = ax1.contourf(x, y, z, 20)
plt.tick_params(which='both', top=False, right=False)
ax2.plot(x, y2, color='g')
plt.tick_params(which='both', top=False, right=False)




axins = inset_axes(ax1,
               width="5%", # width = 10% of parent_bbox width
               height="100%", # height : 50%
               loc=6,
               bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 0., 1, 1),
               bbox_transform=ax1.transAxes,
               borderpad=0,
           )

cbar = plt.colorbar(cont, cax=axins)
plt.savefig('figure.jpg',bbox_inches='tight',dpi=200)
```

[image]

Comment: this doesn't answer the question, which was how to remove the white space between `x=19` and `x=20` on the `contourf` plot

Comment: Wow!  I can't believe I missed that.  When I read the question I read it as asking how to insert the colorbar without interfering with the second plot's scaling relative to the first.  Talk about missing the obvious...oh the shame.

Comment: Although I've learned something new in `inset_axes` so I appreciate the answer. Why does the `plt.tick_params()` work for the upper axis but not the lower one in the above?

Comment: @tnknepp happens to the best of us!

Comment: t.wood: In the code you posted things get a little confusing (at least for me) in regards to the axis orders.  ax2 is upper plot, while ax1 is the lower (normally I would call the upper ax1, and the lower ax2...but that is just preference).  The point being, ax2 remains the last-created axis, therefore your tick_params() command gets issued to it.  You can get around this by explicitly issuing the command directly to the axes, which is how I always do it in my code.  e.g. ax1.tick_params()